# Update <umbraco:macro> with <asp:UpdatePanel>

Tags: razor, asynchronous, updatepanel, master-pages, umbraco

I'm trying to update a razor macroscript in umbraco (within a masterpage) using . What I'm doing is requesting a webservice with specific information using ajax, getting an answer, and want to update the HTML rendered in the razorscript with the updated answers i get from the ajax-request to the webservice. Within the javascript i try to partially postback for an async update of the updatepanel.

I have the following code

Masterpage:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <umbraco:Macro Alias="Macro1" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Javascript:

```
$__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');
```

First of all, is it really possible to manage this? Can I reach the UpdatePanel from the javascript? Second, is it the best way to do it? If not, in what way can I do it more effectively.

Edit:

Code for Ajax-request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "/Handlers/Handler.ashx",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {

       //Here i want to update the UpdatePanel, if possible
       },

       error: function () {

        }
    });
```

Regards
David

Comment: Could you add the code you're using to make the ajax request to the webservice?

Comment: Yes, i've edited the post with the code for request to the handler. The handler itself is requesting the webservice.

Comment: Would it be too much trouble to get a sample of the data that's being returned and the HTML you want to update, then we could give you a better example of how to approach it.

Comment: The thing is that it's just not HTML that's rendered. It's a bit of logic in the macro aswell. Bad practice to put both logic and HTML in the same page perhaps, but that's something we have to refactor in a later stage

Answer (score 1):

Solved it temporarily by just reloading the page after every webservice request. Still wondering if there is a possibility to update a macro by putting it in a UpdatePanel and call it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using a web service, then update the HTML directly with javascript in the callback of the ajax request. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) does a good job at this, but depending on the complexity you may want to use a framework that offers some templating, such as [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), or [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/).

Update Panels are handy, but I don't think it's possible to use them in the way you're attempting to here. ASP.Net controls and razor don't mix well.

Comment: True, I see your point, it's just that there are so many fields that needs to be rendered with javascript in that way, we've considered that solution. Ofcourse it's a possibility, but it's a hell a lot of work, therefore this post if it's possible to update(render out) a macro with an UpdatePanel